# GatsbyImage sourcing from nested GraphQL field

Tags: gatsby, directus, gatsby-image

I'm sourcing data from Directus. There is a field called `image_ext` which contains a link to external resource. I'd like Gatsby to download all images we render and process them so that they are optimized and served locally.

The query looks like this

```
query Articles {
  directus {
    articles {
      image_ext
    }
  }
}
```

All of the guides I found don't mention how to handle some deeply nested field which is not part of some node that you create.

I cannot use regular `img` tag because some of the resources are internal and inaccessible from public.